# How to hide the Edit column in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

Using `GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False` hides `fld1` (the first column), but I want to hide the edit option next to every row. How do you do that?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AttendanceDBConnectionString %>"
                   SelectCommand="SELECT [fld1], [fld2], [fld3],   [fld4], [fld5] FROM [fld6] ORDER BY [fld1], [fld2], [fld3]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
              AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="100">
</asp:GridView>

Protected Sub GridView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound
    GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the "Edit" column on the left side of the `DataGrid`, replace this in your ASPX file:

```
AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
```

With this:

```
AutoGenerateEditButton="False"
```

From the docs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateeditbutton(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When the AutoGenerateEditButton property is set to true, a column ... with an Edit button for each data row is automatically added to the GridView control.

---

If you want to do it in the code-behind, you can access the same property using the ID you set:

```
// test whether the grid is read-only for the current user
if (userIsReadOnly)
    GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = false;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I want to do this programmatically. I am trying to have a group that can edit and other that can only see the table.

Answer (score 0):

There's a data grid view property that you need to look up. It's the row header that you want to hide. See the extra column? You can hide the icon or you can hide the column/header that holds it.

```
datagridview1.RowHeadersVisible = False
```

or

```
datagridview1.ShowEditingIcon = False
```

You can also do this in the Datagridview's properties window.

Comment: it's vb.net, which he also tagged. But in reality, closer to WinForms. I usually do it in the VS property windows.

Comment: I don't see the methods that you mentioned. It shows: Gridview1.Showheader or GridView1.ShowFooter but not any of the two showed above.

Comment: GridView <> DataGridView

Comment: Ah, communication problem then. @Plutonix is right. Sorry about that.